# Vue js: show data from api is not working properly in my code

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js

In my project I'm using JSON API to get data and view them, below is my JSON body and I was able to get the building number for each flat from the following function in `vue.js` by comparing the `id's`:

```
<span v-for="(building,index) in buildings" :key="index">
 <p class="iconB" v-if="building._id.includes(flat.building)">{{building.building_number}} </p>
</span>
```

but my problem is in the `floor_number` i couldn't figure out how to view it and here I have `floor` inside flat array which is the id of the floor that is defined in `floors` array as `_id`, I wanted a way so if I compare them I could get the `floor_number`.

I tried code below but it didn't work

```
<span v-for="(building,index) in buildings" :key="index">                              
 <p class="iconB" v-if="building._id==flat.floor">{{building.floor_number}} </p>
 </span>
```

```
"floors": [
                {
                    "flats": [
                        
                          
                        {
                            "status": "avail",
                            "price": "Not set",
                            "currency": "USD",
                            "end_date": "2022-02-18",
                            "buyer": "Not Set",
                            "buyer_phone_number": "Not Set",
                            "receipt_number_field": "Not Set",
                            "size_unit": "M",
                            "_id": "61e6bccba5da17be7a90fe33",
                            "flat_number": 6,
                            "description": "This is a newly created flat.",
                            "city": "city",
                            "floor": "61e6bccba5da17be7a90fe2d",
                            "building": "61e6bccba5da17be7a90fe2c",
                            "size": "132",
                            "directions": "south",
                            "createdAt": "2022-01-18T13:12:53.447Z",
                            "updatedAt": "2022-02-15T11:15:22.047Z",
                            "__v": 0
                        }
                    ],
                    "_id": "61e6bccba5da17be7a90fe2d",
                    "floor_number": 1,
                    "description": "This is a newly created floor.",
                    "createdAt": "2022-01-18T13:12:53.447Z",
                    "updatedAt": "2022-01-18T13:12:53.447Z",
                    "__v": 0
                },
```

is there a way to do it?

Comment: is floors inside buildings ? Can you provide full buildings variable?

Comment: yes floors inside buildings and building has `building_number` but i couldn't add it cuz bode is too long @gguney

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand your JSON data properly or not. I just came up with below solution as per my understanding. Please let me know if any further discussion/changes required.

You can use two `v-for` to do the comparison between `building._id` & `flat.floor`.

**Demo :**

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    buildings: [{
            flats: [{
        "status": "avail",
        "price": "Not set",
        "currency": "USD",
        "end_date": "2022-02-18",
        "buyer": "Not Set",
        "buyer_phone_number": "Not Set",
        "receipt_number_field": "Not Set",
        "size_unit": "M",
        "_id": "61e6bccba5da17be7a90fe33",
        "flat_number": 6,
        "description": "This is a newly created flat.",
        "city": "city",
        "floor": "61e6bccba5da17be7a90fe2d",
        "building": "61e6bccba5da17be7a90fe2c",
        "size": "132",
        "directions": "south",
        "createdAt": "2022-01-18T13:12:53.447Z",
        "updatedAt": "2022-02-15T11:15:22.047Z",
        "__v": 0
            }],
      _id: "61e6bccba5da17be7a90fe2d",
      floor_number: 1,
      description: "This is a newly created floor.",
      createdAt: "2022-01-18T13:12:53.447Z",
      updatedAt: "2022-01-18T13:12:53.447Z",
      __v: 0
        }]
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <p v-for="building in buildings" :key="building._id">                
    <span v-for="flat in building.flats" :key="flat._id">
      <span class="iconB" v-if="building._id === flat.floor">Floor Number: {{ building.floor_number }}</span>
    </span>
   </p>
</div>
```

Comment: didn't work :\ in JSON above the floor inside flats is the same as _id inside floor so if i compared them i would get the floor_number easily but it's not working

Comment: Kindly check my answer. I gave the way how you can achieve that.